# Displaying Google Maps place card with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I would like to display a place card with Google Maps like the photo below. Does anybody have an idea on how to accomplish that?
It's showing with iFrame embed code, but not with JavaScript...

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3667.38466539855!2d72.64398725007217!3d23.192648084792943!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x395c2a4354a4239f%3A0x4f86b47426db285b!2sIndroda+Nature+Park!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1500619463393" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image]

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You say it's not working with JavaScript, but haven't added any code to your question. Can you add it please?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the functionality is ready-made. You have to:

1. Read the place information through the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).
2. Create an [Info Window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) with your desired content.

Comment: Creating info window is i got..but the thing is that how to display all stuffs in the infowindow like reviews and ratings, etc...

Comment: Map is displayed correctly all i just want is to show the exact same box as like it is there in the posted image in the red box...

Comment: @ChiragDaxini You're gonna have to stop being lazy and do it yourself :B
All the information is there in the API, now create your own box to display it :)

Comment: @ChiragDaxini As I said. I don't think it's ready-made. But the examples in the documentation seem straight-forward. You might even be able to copy the markup from the result of the Embed API.